# Style the Child and not Grandchild?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a 'fancy' navigation, with multiple ul/li. I think my problem is in the CSS with the child selector (>). If you run the code snippet provide you'll notice when you hover over li.first (item one) you can visibly see the div.hover-container although li:first>ul>li has the css with overflow: hidden; along with this div.hover-container is within li.one (example one) so why does it display when I hover over li.>one (other examples).

I am just confused and would love some input on this after staring and testing possible solutions for an hour.

EDIT: I apologize for how messy it looks in the snippet.

```css
/* ================== Example ================ */

.example>ul {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #5A827E;
}

.example>ul>li {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.3%;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.example>ul>li:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: #415E5B;
}

.first>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100.5%;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #415E5B;
}

.first>ul>li {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.first>ul>li:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
}

.hover-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 265px;
  top: 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 535px;
  border: 3px solid gold;
}

.list-container {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 30%;
  border: 3px solid #F2D7E2;
}

.list-container h2 {
  text-align: left;
  color: darkgray;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.list-container ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}


/* ------------------ Example END ---------------- */
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <ul>
    <!-- first navigation container -->
    <li class="first"> Item One
      <ul>
        <!-- dropdown -->
        <li class="one"> Example 1
          <!-- dropdown item -->
          <div class="hover-container">
            <!-- sidebar -->
            <div class="list-container">
              <!-- sidebar content  box-->
              <h2>Content Header One</h2>
              <ul>
                <li>Content One</li>
                <li>Content Two</li>
                <li>Content Three</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- sidebar content box END -->
            <div class="list-container">
              <!-- sidebar content  box-->
              <h2>Content Header One</h2>
              <ul>
                <li>Content One</li>
                <li>Content Two</li>
                <li>Content Three</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- sidebar content box END -->
          </div>
          <!-- sidebar END-->
        </li>
        <!-- dropdown item END -->
        <li>Example 2</li>
        <li>Example 3</li>
        <li>Example 4</li>
        <li>Example 5</li>
        <li>Example 6</li>
        <li>Example 7</li>
        <li>Example 8</li>
        <li>Example 9</li>
        <li>Example 10</li>
      </ul>
      <!-- END of dropdown -->
    </li>
    <!-- main list item END -->
    <li class="second">Item Two</li>
    <li class="third">Item Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `hover-container` div to be shown only when the first `li(Example 1)` is hovered, you need to replace the `.hover-container` you have added with the below CSS:

```
.first>ul>li:first-child:hover .hover-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 265px;
  top: 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 535px;
  border: 3px solid gold;
}
```

Comment: This was the first idea I had to fixing the problem; however, it was too complicated for me, thank you for your input and fix to the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your child selectors seem okay. I think the problem is with your positioning. The .hover-container element has "position: absolute", meaning it's placed relative to its first positioned ancestor (see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). You want to determine if it's overflowing the .first>ul>li element above it, so *that* element needs a "position: relative."

Adding these rules should give the behavior you're looking for:

```
.first>ul>li {
    position: relative;
    ...
}

.first>ul>li:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand why this was happening now, using position: relative; for the parent list item fixed it thank you. I'll be more careful with the positioning in the future

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS property rule defined on `.hover-container` set its position to absolute with respect to `.example>ul>li` which is the nearest ancestor that is a *containing block* ([read about how the browser determines a containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block).)

```
.hover-container {
  /*...*/
  position: absolute;
  /*...*/
}
```

The fix for this is to form a *containing block* with the `li` that is closest ancestor to `.hover-container` by setting its position to relative.

```
.first>ul>li {
  /*...*/
  position: relative;
  /*...*/
}
```

Another fix for this is to set the overflow property to hidden for the closest *containing block* that is an ancestor to `.hover-container`.

```
.first>ul {
  /*...*/
  overflow: hidden;
  /*...*/
}
```

Comment: This makes so much sense to me now, thank you for your help!